# Spring Security failureurl redirect on succesful authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to have two failures URLs based on authentication problem (one when credentials are wrong and second when account isn't activated yet). So I have implemented my own AuthenticationProvider and AuthenticationFailureHandler. The problem now is to get redirected to these urls you first need to fail authentication and then get authenticated correctly.
In more details:

1. You enter main page (`localhost:8080`) but because it requires you to be authenticated you get redirected to `localhost:8080/login`
2. You enter wrong credentials
3. You should be redirected to `localhost:8080/login?badCredentials` bad instead you get redirected to the same page (`localhost:8080/login`)
4. You enter good credentials
5. You get redirected to `localhost:8080/login?badCredentials&continue`, so it is combined failure url with default succesful url?, though you Authentication object is stored in SecurityContext and you got logged in.
6. Though when you now enter wrong credentials or login with not activated account you got redirected correctly so the problem is only the first redirection I think?
7. You manually enter `localhost:8080` (main page) and you are logged in.

I have even created a [video](https://streamable.com/w1s47o) which demonstrates how it works now

AuthenticationProvider

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticationProviderImpl implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationProviderImpl(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            String passwordEnteredByUser = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());

            if (!passwordEncoder.matches(passwordEnteredByUser, userDetails.getPassword())) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
            }

            if (!userDetails.isEnabled()) {
                throw new AccountNotActivatedException("Account not activated");
            }

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails.getUsername(),
                    userDetails.getPassword(),
                    userDetails.getAuthorities()
            );
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

AuthenticationFailureHandler

```java
@Setter
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private String redirectUrl = "login?error";
    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException {

        if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            setRedirectUrl("login?badCredentials");
        } else if (exception instanceof AccountNotActivatedException) {
            setRedirectUrl("login?notActivated");
        }

        this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider,
                          AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
        this.authenticationFailureHandler = authenticationFailureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .permitAll()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)

                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Looks like the problem was that /login also required to be authenticated. Adding this one line `requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()` fix this, though I kinda don't understand how was it able to display correctly when user wasn't authenticated?

Comment: can i ask you why you have written a custom AuthenticationProvider and not used the built in one and just implemented the UserDetailsService interface?

Comment: @Toerktumlare because default authentication provider throws same exception when credentials are bad and when account is not activated, and I wanted to have it separated. I have implemented UserDetailsService because I store users in database and I need to map them from entity to UserDetIls, and I do it in UserDetailsService

Comment: `throws same exception when credentials are bad and when account is not activated, and I wanted to have it separated` this is because of security reasons and best practices. You should never return different out to the client as it can aid hackers and users with malicious intent to see which accounts are not active and which are active when they iterate user credentials.

Comment: The how should I inform user if the credentials are good, but their account is just not activated if spring security treats these two things the same?

Comment: You shouldnt, you should just provide a generic message ”login failed, please check credentisls or contact administraitor”